# Wireless charging wire system (portable charger)

Tags: wireless, charger, iphone, portable

I am an industrial designer that is looking into creating a portable charger that uses MagSafe charging for the new iPhones, but I want the portable chargers to be able to stack. Through the stacking they will be able to share charge and use other portable chargers' batteries. A big problem I am facing is having the portable battery receive charge from another battery/portable charger. These are the PCBs I am currently looking at using:

https://www.newark.com/adafruit/2465/powerboost-1000-lipo-charger-5v/dp/98Y0120?st=2465

[https://www.amazon.com/Gikfun-Wireless-Charger-Circuit-Charging/dp/B073W7P5T8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073W7P5T8)

Currently it can output charge and receive it through USB. Is it possible to have another power source from a wireless portable charger that can charge the battery or be used whilst indirectly connected to a phone? And if so, how do I do it?

My current solution is to attach a wireless charger receiver through the PCBA's micro USB input. Would this work? And if not, what should I do? Wireless charger receiver:

https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/185285107297?chn=ps&_ul=AU&mkevt=1&mkcid=28&var=693059420696
[image]

Comment: The question is reasonably well asked and it's good that you've provided links. The general requirement is clear but it's harder to form a full picture of what yu wish to achieve. When you say "stack" and "share charge" and "receive charge from another ..."  and "..." you probably have a clear picture in mind of the various options and combinations and configurations and ... .  || While I and others are capable of deciding what you MAY wish to achieve it's quite likely that we will get it wrong. If you can provide further detail with block diagrams and more explanation it would probably help.

Comment: Amazon and ebay links do not provide a path to full product detailed information. Therefore those products cannot be said to work or not (as in *would this work?*). The devil is in the detailed circuit design or, in a full product specification/data sheet. Ebay and Amazon do not provide that information nor do they guarantee product quality or manufacturing source quality. You said: *I want the portable chargers to be able to stack* <-- what does this mean? You said: *A big problem I am facing* but then don't reveal details.

Comment: The concept of stack can be explained through the current magsafe system used by apple. Apple uses a wireless magnetic charger that attaches to the back of the phone allowing it to charge. many portable charges now use this technology but I am looking to take it a step further. Using the magnetic charging features I want to allow for multiple portable charges to connect to each other (stack) through the use of magsafe charging. @Andyaka

Comment: The use of an output coil at the top and a receiving coil at the bottom will allow for multiple charges to connect to each other allowing for a theoretically bigger/longer lasting battery. @Andyaka

Comment: grasping my head around the use of PCBs and wiring has been challenging as its not my area of expertise. The only reason i know the linked parts work is through a YouTube video of so0meone making a portable magsafe charger. The addition of a receiving coil has stumped me as I don't want to start experimenting when there is a lithium battery involved as I'm not confident in anything electrical in terms of wiring. @RussellMcMahon

Comment: Ill add my early thumbnail drawing which i hope help visualise it. its basically a portable Magsafe charger with an output coil on the top and a receiving coil on the bottom allowing for other batteries to connect to each other wirelessly. I hope this rough explanation helps. But to sum it up the receiving coil is my problem as I don't know how to connect it to the battery or how it will work when a portable charger is connected to another whilst its charging a phone. will it hold charge? swap to using the power of the added charger? or charge the currently being used battery?@RussellMcMahon

Comment: @ThomasThwaites - Hi, This question is effectively a repeat (with more info) of your [previous question](/q/647625). Please don't repost questions. On Stack Exchange, the correct behaviour is to edit a question to improve it, not to repost it. You didn't get an answer to your previous question, so there is [this advice](/help/no-one-answers) in the [help]. Please review there and also the [tour] to see how Stack Exchange rules & etiquette differ from typical forums. On this occasion, as an exception, I will delete your previous question rather than forcing you to update that one.